# In Prometheus, does David dislike humans?

Tags: alien-franchise, prometheus

In the movie, does it ever state that David has disdain for humans in general?

Is there any confirmation of his opinion of his fellow crewmates?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Based on the earlier [Jon Spaihts screenplay](https://web.archive.org/web/20141029022629/http://www.joblo.com/scripts/Alien-Engineers-ORIGINAL-PROMETHEUS-SCRIPT.pdf), David's feelings toward his crewmates (and humanity in general) are a **lot** clearer. He seems to admire their cold intellectual pursuits but expresses a hearty dislike of their emotional outbursts and physical frailty. In short, he wishes they were more like him, he feels that he's forced to work with inferior beings and he feels like he's been the subject of slavery:

> **DAVID :** *Your hypothesis is...bold. **The audacity of it**. Your climate data’s undeniable: the Holocene Epoch was engineered.*

and

> **DAVID :** *Being shaped like you, I can use spaces and equipment designed for you.
>   **But I’m not so limited. I hear frequencies you can’t hear. I see wavelengths of light invisible to you. I move faster. Exert greater
>   force.***
>   The scientists look at DAVID in wonder.
>   **WATTS :** *You see yourself as a superman.*
>   **DAVID :** *No.*
>   He turns his unearthly eyes on them.
>   **DAVID** (CONT’D) : **Not a man at all.**

and

> **WATTS :** *I can’t think about this now!*
>   **DAVID :** *You should.*
>   (he sighs)
>   I understand. You’re emotional.
>   **WATTS :** *I’m human.*
>   **DAVID :** *That’s what I mean.*

and

> Watts points at the door DAVID just opened.
>   **WATTS :** *How did you do that?*
>   **A flicker of disappointment in the android’s face. Contempt.**
>   **DAVID :** *Ah. You don’t see.* (he smiles)

and

> **DAVID :** ***You’re all so stupid.***
>   Watts gasps in shock - at the malice in DAVID’s voice as much as the closing door. She dives out. Just in time.
>   **DAVID** (CONT'D): ***Stupid and slow.***

and

> **DAVID** (Speaking to the Facehugger) : *I know. I met my creators the day I was born. **I was disappointed too.***